# Why (x'Ay)^2 <=(x'Ax)(y'Ay), when A is positive definite?

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let A be a positive definite matrix. Why then is

$(x'Ay)^2 \le (x'Ax)(y'Ay)$, where (x'Ax) and (y'Ay) are quadratic forms?

Comment: Because this is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I was not aware of that - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \sqrt{A}$, since $A$ is positive definite. Now use Cauchy Schwarz inequality on $Bx$ and $By$.